# ¿Cómo realizar una instancia única de mi aplicación?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Deseo realizar una instancia única de una aplicación desarrollada en *C#* *Windows Forms*, estas son las condiciones:

1. Que la aplicación sea una instancia única
2. Que la aplicación de instancia única sea por sesión de *Windows*

Es decir que sea una instancia única por cada sesión de *Windows*,
Además que no se cierre la aplicación iniciada en otra sesión de *Windows*, dado que al volver a la anterior sesión este abierta la aplicación, ya que es un contador de tiempo.

He intentado lo siguiente:

```
static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new frmLogin());

        new MiApp().Run(new string[0]);
    }
}
class MiApp: WindowsFormsApplicationBase
{
    public MiApp(): base(AuthenticationMode.ApplicationDefined)
    {
        IsSingleInstance = true;
        ShutdownStyle = ShutdownMode.AfterMainFormCloses;
    }
    protected override void OnCreateMainForm()
    {
        MainForm = new frmLogin();
    }
    protected override bool OnStartup(StartupEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        return base.OnStartup(eventArgs);
    }
    protected override void OnStartupNextInstance(StartupNextInstanceEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        base.OnStartupNextInstance(eventArgs);
    }
}
```

... y también con la clase *Mutex*, pero cuando cambio de sesión de *Windows* la aplicación, no inicia en esta otra sesión.

Answer (score 1):

Yo lo que suelo utilizar es el siguiente código. Básicamente, busco si hay algun proceso abierto con el mismo nombre que el de mi aplicación, y si existe pongo el foco el la aplicación que ya está abierta y cierro. Sería algo asi:

```
public static void Main()  
{
     Application.EnableVisualStyles();
     Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

     Process[] procesos = Process.GetProcessesByName("NombreDeTuAplicación");
     bool procesoAbierto = false;
     if (procesos.Length > 1)
     {
        foreach (Process proceso in procesos)
        {
            IntPtr frameworkHandle = proceso.MainWindowHandle;

            if (frameworkHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                 procesoAbierto = true;
                 WINDOWPLACEMENT wp = new WINDOWPLACEMENT();
                 wp.showCmd = 3;
                 SetForegroundWindow(frameworkHandle);
                 SetWindowPlacement(frameworkHandle, ref wp);
             }
         }
     }
     if (procesoAbierto == false)
     {
          Application.Run(new frmLogin());
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

En este [articulo](http://sanity-free.org/143/csharp_dotnet_single_instance_application.html) decribe como obtener una instancia unica de tu aplicacion por ejemplo:

```
static class Program
{
    static Mutex mutex = new Mutex(true, "{8F6F0AC4-B9A1-45fd-A8CF-72F04E6BDE8F}");
    [STAThread]
    static void Main() {
        if(mutex.WaitOne(TimeSpan.Zero, true)) {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
            mutex.ReleaseMutex();
        } else {
            MessageBox.Show("only one instance at a time");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Cómo generaste el GUID ?

Comment: en realidad no importa, solo es un string para identificar el nombre del mutex, siempre es buena practica el uso de guid's como identificadores.

Answer (score 0):

No indicas si es Forms o WPF, pero para WPF:
para la condición de instancia única sigue estos pasos:

1- Crea una clase llamada "WpfSingleInstance" en la raíz del proyecto y debe lucir así:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Threading;

namespace TU-NAMESPACE
{
    public static class WpfSingleInstance
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Processing single instance in <see cref="SingleInstanceModes"/> <see cref="SingleInstanceModes.ForEveryUser"/> mode.
        /// </summary>
        internal static void Make()
        {
            Make(SingleInstanceModes.ForEveryUser);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Processing single instance.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="singleInstanceModes"></param>
        internal static void Make(SingleInstanceModes singleInstanceModes)
        {
            var appName = Application.Current.GetType().Assembly.ManifestModule.ScopeName;

            var windowsIdentity = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
            var keyUserName = windowsIdentity != null ? windowsIdentity.User.ToString() : String.Empty;

            // Be careful! Max 260 chars!
            var eventWaitHandleName = string.Format(
                "{0}{1}",
                appName,
                singleInstanceModes == SingleInstanceModes.ForEveryUser ? keyUserName : String.Empty
                );

            try
            {
                using (var eventWaitHandle = EventWaitHandle.OpenExisting(eventWaitHandleName))
                {
                    // It informs first instance about other startup attempting.
                    eventWaitHandle.Set();
                }

                // Let's terminate this posterior startup.
                // For that exit no interceptions.
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }
            catch
            {
                // It's first instance.

                // Register EventWaitHandle.
                using (var eventWaitHandle = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.AutoReset, eventWaitHandleName))
                {
                    ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject(eventWaitHandle, OtherInstanceAttemptedToStart, null, Timeout.Infinite, false);
                }

                RemoveApplicationsStartupDeadlockForStartupCrushedWindows();
            }
        }

        private static void OtherInstanceAttemptedToStart(Object state, Boolean timedOut)
        {
            RemoveApplicationsStartupDeadlockForStartupCrushedWindows();
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { try { Application.Current.MainWindow.Activate(); } catch { } }));
        }

        internal static DispatcherTimer AutoExitAplicationIfStartupDeadlock;

        public static void RemoveApplicationsStartupDeadlockForStartupCrushedWindows()
        {
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                AutoExitAplicationIfStartupDeadlock =
                    new DispatcherTimer(
                        TimeSpan.FromSeconds(6),
                        DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle,
                        (o, args) =>
                        {
                            if (Application.Current.Windows.Cast<Window>().Count(window => !Double.IsNaN(window.Left)) == 0)
                            {
                                // For that exit no interceptions.
                                Environment.Exit(0);
                            }
                        },
                        Application.Current.Dispatcher
                    );
            }),
                DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle
                );
        }
    }

    public enum SingleInstanceModes
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Do nothing.
        /// </summary>
        NotInited = 0,

        /// <summary>
        /// Every user can have own single instance.
        /// </summary>
        ForEveryUser,
    }
}
```

Luego sobreescribe el evento OnStartup en App.xaml.cs

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
  WpfSingleInstance.Make();
  base.OnStartup(e);
}
```

Con esto tu aplicativo se abrirá 1 sola vez.
El código no lo hice yo, pero lo tengo hace muchos años así que no recuerdo su origen pero todos los créditos a su autor correspondiente. 
Un saludo.

Comment: Es en Forms el codigo que envié.